# If $f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is the affine approximation to $f$ at $x_0$, is $f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ the linear approximation?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x_0$, the affine approximation of $f$ at $x_0$ is $f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$.

So, would that mean that $f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is the linear approximation?

Comment: what is the value of $f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ at $x_0$? do you think that it is an approximation?

Comment: People often use "linear" in the sense of "affine" when talking about approximations. So if a text say "the linear approximation of $f$" I would take it to mean $f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ as it doesn't really make sense to take about a purely linear approximation

Comment: So, what would be the linear approximation? Would it just be $f'(x_0)\cdot x$?

Comment: To maybe clarify what's already been said: When people talk about "linear" approximations they are strictly speaking talking about _affine_ approximations. You ask so then what's the linear approximation. If you mean "linear" literally, as opposed to affine, then functions in general don't _have_ linear approximations. If you were asked to find the linear approximation it was actually intended that you find the affine approximation.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let's say we take the tangent line of $f(x_0)$, then apply a transformation so that now $(x_0, f(x_0))$ is the origin, then wouldn't this be the actual linear approximation?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "a transformation so that now $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is the origin. I also cannot understand why you continue to ask the same question! If we mean "linear" in the strict sense, so affine functions are not linear, then in general there _is_ no linear approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say only if $f(x_0) = 0$, if you mean linear in the sense of linear algebra, in contrast to affine.

$T(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is the best first order approximation, this is also called linear. Also functions $y = m x + n$ are called linear, the special case $y = m x$ proportional.

The graph of $T$ is a line, which for $f(x_0) \ne 0$ is not containing the origin.

In the terms of linear algebra this is not linear, but affine. And these two different kinds of "linear" seem to be the problem here.

Comment: So, what would be the linear approximation? Would it just be $f'(x_0)\cdot x$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a derivative near $x_0$ then it can be approximated by an affine  function but not necessarily linear(i.e. crosses zero at $x_0$). 
Sometimes you may find people referring to affine as linear but don't bother with the terms remember that it has the derivative as a slope and it crosses the point near which it was defined.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $f'(x_0) \, (x-x_0)$ is a linear approximation of the difference $f(x)-f(x_0)$.

This is the same thing as an affine approximation of $f(x)$, so people don't bother very much with the distinction.